# How can I resize or delete a label to make possible the redraw of the NSView?

Tags: swift, macos, label, drawrect

I am trying to display a bar chart view, but every time that the NSView that contains it resizes, the labels are not deleted or resized and shows something like that: [bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzDK3.png) I used bordered labels to make it easy to see. The labels I'm talking about are the ones in the horizontal axis.

The problem is that I add the labels on the `override func drawRect(rect:NSRect){}` inside the NSView subclass. I put the labels there because when the view resizes the labels follow the bar chart and changes its size and works well, but create new labels instead of redrawing its.
How can I fix that problem?

I have a for loop inside `override func drawRect(rect:NSRect){}` that call this function 12 times:

```
var label = NSTextField()
private func showLabel (valor: String, frame: CGRect) -> NSTextField      {
    label = NSTextField(frame: frame)
    label.stringValue = valor
    label.textColor = NSColor.blueColor()
    label.editable = false
    label.bordered = true
    label.alignment = .Center
    let fontSize = label.font!.pointSize;

    label.font = NSFont(name: "Arial", size: fontSize)
    return label
}
```

Here the drawRect method

```
override func drawRect(rect:NSRect){
    removeLabel()
    let pathRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 1, 1)
    let path = NSBezierPath(rect: pathRect)

    path.lineWidth = 1
    NSColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    NSColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    path.fill()
    path.stroke()

    eixosDrawing()

    // Bars
    barresDrawing()

    // Eixos
    eixosHoritzontals()

}
```

And the function that calls the label function

```
// Creating the Labels

func eixosHoritzontals () {

    let drawingRect = elDrawRect()
    let arrayY = dataSource?.infoGraficsView(self) ?? [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    let arrayX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    let (espaiUnaBarra, espaiUnaSeparacio) = propBarres (CGFloat(arrayY.count))

    for i in 0..<arrayY.count {

        let posicioX = CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect) + (espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra) * CGFloat(i) + espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra / 2
        let posicioY = CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect) - (self.bounds.size.height * 0.15) / 4
        let centre = CGPoint( x: posicioX, y: posicioY )
        let size = CGSize(width: espaiUnaBarra + espaiUnaSeparacio * 3/2, height: self.bounds.height * 0.15 / 4 )
        let rectu = CGRect(center: centre, size: size)

        // Adding
        let text = showLabel(String(arrayX[i]), frame: rectu)
        self.addSubview(text)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by using that:

```
for subview in self.subviews { // which self is the NSView subclass created by myself
    if subview is NSLabel {
        subview.removeFromSuperview() // delete all the labels added no matter how many of them are there.
    }
}
```

I hope it can help somebody!